# Calling MySQL exe using PHP exec doesn’t work

Tags: mysql

I have a simple script:

```
<?php

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'password';
  $db = 'BPOJob';
  $file =dirname(__FILE__).'\\'.'job_create.sql';
  $mySQLDir='"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe"';     

  $cmd = $mySQLDir.' -h '.$dbhost.' --user='.$dbuser.' --password='.$dbpass.' < "'.$file.'"';

   exec($cmd,$out,$retval);
   echo "\n";
echo ($retval);

?>
```

The thing is when I run the above command in PHP.exe, it doesn't work; I got a 1 as a return value from exec.

But if I run the command line directly by calling

```
mysql.exe -h localhost --user=admin --password=password < job_create.sql
```

Then the .sql file can run.

Is there anything I miss?

**Edit: Sorry! Wrong info. I have edited the question and it's still valid.**

Comment: Hm, shouldn't you exec $cmd instead of $mySQLDir?

Comment: @Node: Hm, shouldn't you write answers to the answers section? :)

Comment: Hm, It feelt like a comment for me. :P But as demanded, posted as answer, now go and vote me down. ;)

Comment: Shouldn't this question be posted in stackoverflow instead?

Comment: this belongs on stackoverflow.com ...

Comment: @Alnitak: I think you could argue about that. Somehow it does, somehow it doesn't.

Comment: it _definitely_ does - it's a PHP problem, not a server admin one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found the solution](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/05/run-sql-file-from-php.html): you need to explicitly enclosed the `$cmd` in quote:

```
 exec('"'.$cmd.'"',$out ,$retval);
```

This is the full script, for your reference:

```
<?php

  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'password';
  $db = 'BPOJob';
  $file =dirname(__FILE__).'\\'.'job_create.sql';
  $mySQLDir='"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe"';     

  $cmd = $mySQLDir.' -h '.$dbhost.' --user='.$dbuser.' --password='.$dbpass.' < "'.$file.'"';

   exec('"'.$cmd.'"',$out,$retval);
   echo "\n";
echo ($retval);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm, shouldn't you exec $cmd instead of $mySQLDir?

EDIT: Try to echo $cmd maybe you could see an error.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces in the command line are probably being treated as separators, so it's actually trying to run:

```
c:\program
```

with arguments:

```
files ...
```

Try enclosing the whole of the executable path in double-quotes as it's passed to `exec()`, so that the windows shell knows that it's supposed to be one word.

Comment: Good point.  +1

Comment: I thought it's already enclosed?

 $mySQLDir='"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe"';

Comment: so it is - I couldn't see the ' " " ' sequence the first time